# Laravel Homestead Hangs on SSH Auth Method

Tags: php, laravel, ssh, vagrant, homestead

I'm having an issue with Laravel Homestead on Windows 7. When I run vagrant up it's hanging on:

`SSH auth method: private key`

Not sure why this is. I've tried a number of solutions. Here the auth stuff from my homestead.yaml file:

```
authorize: C:/Users/Kim.Ward/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - C:/Users/Kim.Ward/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I have also tried:

```
authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I've attempted adding:

```
   config.ssh.private_key_path = "C:/Users/Kim.Ward/.ssh/id_rsa"
```

and:

```
config.ssh.username = "vagrant"
config.ssh.password = "vagrant"
```

I can confirm that virtualisation is enabled and I'm using an i5 6500.

If I check virtual box while the box is booting and I can see in the preview window a login prompt. I can also double click the instance in virtual box and it'll open up and allow me to login but it doesn't look like the set up process is complete.

I am using Virtual Box version 5.1.18 and Vagrant v1.9.1.
I have tried with various other minor versions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm running out of ideas that this point.

Thanks,

Kim

Comment: Does it hang indefinitely or eventually timeout?

Comment: Ah sorry. Yes it times out.

Comment: can you login from virtualbox directly or not ? enable the gui mode

Comment: I can login via gui but the code folder is not mapped.

Comment: do you have the `/home/vagrant/.ssh` folder and set with correct permission ?

Comment: The .ssh folder exists with permissions "drwx------" and there is an authorized_keys file present with a key in it.

Comment: did u try minor versions of virtualbox too, try 5.1.14

Comment: Sadly the same issue occurs when 5.1.14 Kevin.a

Comment: No idea why but a clean install of windows fixed this issue.